# Run post install file replace before creating service

Tags: inno-setup

I have configured the below script to ask the user for an IP address as part of the install wizard, this address gets written to a config file which the application will reference to know where to communicate with. 
However currently, the service is created before the configuration file is updated (`Run` section happens before `CurStep = ssPostInstall`), so the default value has already been read from the file before it is updated. 
This means that a further manual service restart is currently required to get the application to communicate.

I understand it is possible to have the `Run` section happen after the `ssPostInstall`.

I have read the article [Inno Setup: How to run a code procedure in Run section or before Run section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257808/inno-setup-how-to-run-a-code-procedure-in-run-section-or-before-run-section) which suggests I can use the `BeforeInstall:` parameter as part of the run command to perform the `CurStepChanged` procedure first. However, this leads to an error of

> Required function or procedure 'CurStepChanged' found but not with a compatible prototype.

I also tried moving the run line and command above the `CurStepChanged` section (to match the article mentioned as closely as possible), but this still returned the same error.

Can anyone offer some guidance as to where I am going wrong with the configuration?

```pascal
[Code]

var
  PrimaryServerPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function FileReplaceString(ReplaceString: string):boolean;
var
  MyFile : TStrings;
  MyText : string;
begin
  Log('Replacing in file');
  MyFile := TStringList.Create;

  try
    Result := true;

    try
      MyFile.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}' + '\providers\print\win\print-provider.conf'));
      Log('File loaded');
      MyText := MyFile.Text;

      { Only save if text has been changed. }
      if StringChangeEx(MyText, 'REPLACE_WITH_CUSTOMER_IP', ReplaceString, True) > 0 then
      begin;
        Log('IP address inserted');
        MyFile.Text := MyText;
        MyFile.SaveToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}' + '\providers\print\win\print-provider.conf'));
        Log('File saved');
      end;
    except
      Result := false;
    end;
  finally
    MyFile.Free;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PrimaryServerPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(
      wpWelcome, 'Application Server Details', 'Where is installed?',
      'Please specify the IP address or hostname of your ' +
        'Primary Application Server, then click Next.');
  PrimaryServerPage.Add('Primary Application Server IP/Hostname:', False);
end;   

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('File installed, replacing IP address');
    FileReplaceString(PrimaryServerPage.Values[0]);
  end;
end;


[run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create PCPrintProvider start= auto binPath= ""{app}\providers\print\win\pc-print.exe PCPrintProvider"" depend= Spooler" ; Flags: runhidden ; BeforeInstall: CurStepChanged
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "start PCPrintProvider" ; Flags: runhidden ; BeforeInstall: CurStepChanged
```

Comment: Did you try using **Check** param in [run] section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your own procedure for the [`BeforeInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall):

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; \
    Parameters: "create PCPrintProvider start= auto binPath= ""{app}\providers\print\win\pc-print.exe PCPrintProvider"" depend= Spooler"; \
    Flags: runhidden; BeforeInstall: ReplaceIPAddress
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure ReplaceIPAddress;
begin
  FileReplaceString(PrimaryServerPage.Values[0]);
end;
```

Comment: Where should I insert the additional code? I already have the CurStepChanged procedure, is this inserted within that or kept seperate?

Comment: Separate. It has nothing to with `CurStepChanged`. And you actually need to remove the `CurStepChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **[Check](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck)** param

```
[run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create PCPrintProvider start= auto binPath= ""{app}\providers\print\win\pc-print.exe PCPrintProvider"" depend= Spooler" ; Flags: runhidden ; Check: IsIpChanged;

[code]
function IsIpChanged: Boolean;
begin
    FileReplaceString(PrimaryServerPage.Values[0]);
    Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: While this would indeed work, it's rather a hack, and quite non-intuitive.